# "Multiple enumeration" form for reStructuredText (Sphinx) lists

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is it possible to make auto-enumerated list in ReStructuredText (Sphinx) like

```
1. Point 1
1.1. Point 1.1.
1.2. Point 1.2.
2. Point 2.
```

Are any directives or other ways for that?

It should be similar to section numbering (http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#automatic-section-numbering)

Thanks in advance, Denis

Comment: Solution is here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sphinx-users/Sa8MpXdAQeM

Comment: "This case is, however not transferable to ordinary ordered lists" does that mean there is no solution?